# The value of the state is not updating in the following code using react and react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Firstly the profile is set to default values. Then data is fetched and then I am trying to set the default value to the fetched values

```
 const Profile = () => {
   const [profile, setProfile] = useState({
   name3: "Naman Aggarwal",
   username2: "_naman.agg",
   bio2: "There's nothing holding me back, Nsut'23",
   email2: "naman.aggarwal2001@gmail.com",
});


useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/show")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res2) => {
    console.log(res2.foundUser[0]);

    setProfile((prevValue) => {
      // console.log(profile);
      const { name, username, bio, email } = res2.foundUser[0];
      const { name3, username2, bio2, email2 } = profile;
      return {
        ...prevValue,
        [name3]: name,
        [username2]: username,
        [bio2]: bio,
        [email2]: email,
      };
    });

   // console.log(profile);
   });
  }, []);
 }
```

This assignment is not working I guess.

Comment: Can you post what you get in `console.log(res2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow!

I do not fully understand the issue at hand, it would be helpful if you could provide the expected result and actual result, but I can see where things can go wrong in this code.

In your `useEffect` function you are returning the following object:

```
return {
    ...prevValue,
    [name3]: name,
    [username2]: username,
    [bio2]: bio,
    [email2]: email,
  };
```

Now, if you expect the object to be `{ name3: 'x', username2: 'y', bio2: 'z' }` That wont happen. Because you are not saving the object as those values, you are wrapping each key in square brackets `[]` which means that instead of applying literally `name3` `username2` `bio2` you are applying its values.

So instead of `{ name3: 'x', username2: 'y', bio2: 'z' }` you will be getting `{ x: 'x', y: 'y', z: 'z' }` (Basically you will get the value of the property instead of key name).

I would try modifying the return function to look like this:

```
return {
...prevValue,
name3: name,
username2: username,
bio2: bio,
email2: email,
};
```

I hope I got the issue right if I didn't please leave a comment so we can discuss further.

Comment: This is also not updating the state.

Comment: res2.foundUser[0] is    {_id: "5f25a2bc2b291b39c80075b6", name: "Nandini", username: "Nandini", bio: "Nandini", email: null, …}
bio: "Nandini"
email: null
name: "Nandini"
username: "Nandini"
__v: 0
_id: "5f25a2bc2b291b39c80075b6"}

Comment: Now what I want is this.....I want to change the name3 of profile from "Naman Aggarwal" to "Nandini" which is fetched from the database and rest of the properties too.

Comment: and to check the changes...I am just uncommenting the console.log(profile) in the question. It remains the same.

Comment: Ah, you cannot check the `console.log` in the place you've put it. It is because useState is asynchronous - meaning you will always see old value there. Try using console.log outside of useEffect (just put it in the render)

Comment: What was that....well this solved the problem and your above solution too. Thank you for your fast solution.  Now the only thing I didn't understand is that asynchronous part and why after fetching data it don't reflect in the console.

Comment: Asynchronous means - in this exact your case, that it will first run `useState` => here a lot of changes are being made, but not immediately, so instead of keeping you waiting, it will go to the next line, which, in your case is `console.log` which logs the old state, since this `useState` async function is still in motion, and not yet done. Take a look at this article: https://javascript.info/async-await#:~:text=The%20word%20%E2%80%9Casync%E2%80%9D%20before%20a,in%20a%20resolved%20promise%20automatically.&text=So%2C%20async%20ensures%20that%20the,wraps%20non%2Dpromises%20in%20it.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Ok so to make the console print the correct state I have to use async and await.

Comment: Usually you would use async and await functions to get the result and then safely console.log, but this `useState` is a common thing that will happen, and its much easier to just move `console.log` to the render, so you will see every update that gets there, also you could explore some of React / Redux's dev tools for easier state tracking. :)